# UWP Version Numbers

Tags: uwp, appxmanifest

How do I format my version number in my AppxManifest for UWP? I'm trying everything I can but nothing seems to work. The compiler always returns:

> C:\AdaptSource\Xivic\Adapt.Presentation.Xivic.UWP\bin\x86\Release\AppxManifest.xml
>   : error APPX0501: Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest
>   validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line
>   10, Column 109, Reason: '43.92.00' violates pattern constraint of
>   '(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])(.(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])){3}'.
>   The attribute 'Version' with value '43.92.00' failed to parse.
>   [C:\AdaptSource\Xivic\Adapt.Presentation.Xivic.UWP\Adapt.Presentation.Xivic.UWP.csproj]

Comment: Also, the leading zeros in the third position [43(*first position*).92(*second position*).00(*third position*)] are not supported

Answer (score 4):

It needs to be 4 numbers. See MSDN doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering

Comment: Is this always the case? Sometimes I get to the upload page and it complains that the last digit isn't a zero. Or maybe I'm misinterpreting the error.

Comment: It's always 4 number segments. In the example you gave (43.92.00) you only had 3. Also the double zero ('00") is not ok.